# mssql - Use inner join to display column values in same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table holding clock-in/out times for several employees:

```
username            datetime                 action

test.user           2016-10-05 07:30:49      0
test.user           2016-10-05 08:50:00      1
test.user           2016-10-05 08:53:49      0
test.user           2016-10-05 13:35:47      1
```

I want to obtain a result set with each row containing the username, and a pair of clock in/out actions for that username (0 is clock in, 1 is clock out).

What I have so far is this:

```
select a.username, a.datetime as clockIN, b.datetime as clockOUT 
from attendance a
inner join
attendance b
on 
(
a.username = b.username
and datepart(dd, a.datetime) = datepart(dd, b.datetime)
and datepart(mm, a.datetime) = datepart(mm, b.datetime)
and datepart(yy, a.datetime) = datepart(yy, b.datetime)
and a.action = 0
and b.action = 1
and a.datetime < b.datetime
)
order by a.datetime asc
```

And this is the result

```
username        clockIN                clockOUT   

test.user       2016-10-05 07:30:00    2016-10-05 08:50:00 
test.user       2016-10-05 07:30:00    2016-10-05 13:35:47    
test.user       2016-10-05 08:53:49    2016-10-05 13:35:47
```

Desired result would be:

```
username        clockIN                clockOUT   

test.user       2016-10-05 07:30:00    2016-10-05 08:50:00   
test.user       2016-10-05 08:53:49    2016-10-05 13:35:47
```

Any ideas on how to ommit the second row from the results?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the logic by which the second record is being omitted?

Comment: What if two clockOUT have the same value but different clockIN values?

Comment: I'm confused...does the user check in twice at the same time and check out at different times? Or are they separate users?

Comment: A user is not allowed to clock-in twice in a row. Clock-in is always followed by a clock-out. These actions always come in pairs. A clock-out action has only one corresponding clock-in action.

Comment: The second row is invalid because the correct pairs are 7:30 - 08:50 and 08:53 - 13:35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT
  a1.username, a1.datetime as clockIN
, (SELECT top 1 a2.datetime FROM #attendance a2
   where a1.username = a2.username and a2.action = 1 and a2.datetime > a1.datetime order by a2.datetime) AS clockout
FROM #attendance a1 WHERE action = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!